# Why is $\sec(\pi/2)$, when approaching from the left equal to negative infinity and not positive infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, graphing-functions, infinity

I thought that as $\sec(\pi/2)$ is equal to $1/\cos(\pi/2)$, and given that cos function is positive before $\pi/2$, that it would be positive infinity instead of negative infinity, when $\sec(\pi/2)$ is being approached from the left moving towards the right.

Comment: Where did you find this claim ? I agree your argument.

Comment: If $0< x <\frac\pi 2$ then $\cos x > 0$ and $\sec x > 0$ and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \sec(\frac \pi 2-\epsilon)=\lim_{x\to \frac {\pi}2^-}\sec x = +\infty$.  Now I would say the limit from the "left" the lim where $x$ than be approaching is positive infinity.  Likewise if $\pi > x > \frac \pi 2$ then $\sec x < 0$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\sec (\frac \pi 2 + \epsilon) =\lim_{x\to\frac \pi 2^+}\sec x = -\infty$.  I'd say that means the limit "from the right" is negative infinity. I guess you heard it from someone who interpretted differently.

Comment: Of course "left" and "right" are rather informal and sort of meaningless....

Comment: Okay,  as to Can Turken's answer, if you view $x$ as and *angle* then left and right can be *interpreted* as clockwise and counterclock was and $x$ is to the *right* of $\frac \pi 2$ if it is clockwise to $\frac \pi 2$. i.e. when it is *LESS* than $\frac \pi 2$.   ... That may have been what the person meat.  I can't say how must people would use the worlds "left" and "right" in this case but *I* would never even think to use left and right for clockface (it reverses for the bottom half of the face and doesn't apply near $0$ and $\pi$ but "up/down" do; it's a complete mess IMO)

Answer (score 0):

As you said "...  cos function is positive before pi/2 ..." and "before pi/2" means you are less than pi/2, you are on the "right" side of pi/2 considering unit circle! So, if you approach pi/2 "from right" you get infinity.

Simiarly if you approach pi/2 "from left", you are on the left side of pi/2 considering unit circle and since cos function is negative there, you get minus infinity.

However, on the real line you are right that,

"$\pi/2$ being approached from the left moving towards the right" is denoted by $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to (\pi/2)^-}$ which means $x<\pi/2$ and $x \to \pi/2$.

"$\pi/2$ being approached from the right moving towards the left" is denoted by $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to (\pi/2)^+}$ which means $x>\pi/2$ and $x \to \pi/2$.

Comment: ""before pi/2" means you are less than pi/2, you are on the "right" side of pi/2!"  How you figure? If $x < \frac \pi 2$ then I imagine nearly everyone would say $x$ is one the "*left*" side of $\frac \pi 2$.  I can't see why you think you were to the right.

Comment: Drawing unit circle and moving countercloakwise I thought at first

Comment: Oh, I guess one could reasonably view it as such. That may have been what the person the OP is quoting was thinking that way.

Comment: Hi Can are you sure about this:"/2 being approached from the left moving towards the right" is denoted by lim→(/2)+,"/2 being approached from the right moving towards the left" is denoted by lim→(/2)− " I thought it was the other way around

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I was also confused :) I edited my answer.